# Iterating std::string elements

Tags: c++, string

does it take constant time to move the iterator to elements of string in following:

```
std::string str // string of size 100 MB
std::string::iterator iter = str.begin();
std::advance(iter, str.size()-1);
```

would it take constant time as in searching by index?

```
char c = str[str.size()-1];
```

Comment: Use string::iterator only if you really want to mutate. It triggers copy-on-write and this causes confusing profiling results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's correct.  This is guaranteed by the C++ standard (§24.3, Iterator operations):

> Since only random access iterators
>   provide + and - operators, the library
>   provides two function templates
>   advance and distance. These function
>   templates use + and - for random
>   access iterators (and are, therefore,
>   constant time for them);

Answer (score 0):

Why on earth would you use the top code instead of str.end() - 1?

Edit: Or str.back(), which is far more container-generic.

Comment: It doesn't rely on iter being a Random Access Iterator. In the specific case this isn't important but could if it is too simplified.